# Conditional uniform convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, uniform-convergence, conditional-convergence

I am wondering if it makes sense to say that a (uniform) convergence in probability is conditional on a random variable. Or maybe, there is another way to express that.

Assume two real-valued random variables $X_n$ and $Y_n(\theta)$, where $Y_n$ depends on some parameter $\theta \in \Theta$. I know that $\Theta$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Convergence in probability**: I show that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\theta \in \Theta$, $\mathbb{P}\left(|Y_n(\theta) - \mathbb{E}(Y_n(\theta)|X_n)|>\varepsilon | X_n\right) \to 0$ as $n$ grows to infinity. So, I conclude that $Y_n(\theta)$ converges in probability to $\mathbb{E}(Y_n(\theta)|X_n)$ conditionally on $X_n$. Is that terminology correct?

**Uniform convergence in probability**: I also show that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, $Y_n(\theta)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y_n(\theta)|X_n)$ are continuously differentiable in $\theta$ and their derivative are bounded on the compact $\Theta$. Can I also say that $Y_n(\theta)$ converges uniformly in probability to $\mathbb{E}(Y_n(\theta)|X_n)$ conditionally on $X_n$?

Comment: You are considering the random variable $Z_n=\mathbb{E}(Y_n(\Theta)\mid X_n)$. If what you're looking for is a "diagonal argument" (i.e. $X_n$ and $Y_n$ move at the same rate) the convergence you're talking about is simply a convergence of a sequence of random variables

Comment: Exactly. I know. But I am dealing with people who know conditional probabilities. They have a good intuition about that. But they don't understand that a conditional expectation is a random variable (lol). So I would like to tell them that I have a uniform convergence in probability conditionally on $X_n$. But I  don't know if this is correct.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Also, there is little difference with the standard convergence. I also use the condition $X_n$ in the probability.

Comment: The problem that I find in this "formulation" is that saying "conditionally to $X_n$", while taking a limit in $n$, is confusing because $X_n$ is also moving...

Comment: Yes, you're right. So, If we assume that $X_1$, ..., $X_n$ have the same $\sigma$-algebra, maybe this makes sense? The probabilities and the expectations would be conditionally on this $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: In what sense is $\mathbb{P}(|Y_n(\theta)-\mathbb{E}[Y_n(\theta)|X_n]| > \varepsilon | X_n)$ converging to zero?  I assume you mean almost surely, but want to check to make sure.

Comment: What makes sense is that. But I don't understand how this turns into convergence almost surely.

Comment: @Ari.stat I'm not sure I understand what you mean there.  $\mathbb{P}(A_n|X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables (where the events $A_n$ can be arbitrary, in this case $|Y_n(\theta)-\mathbb{E}[Y_n(\theta)|X_n]| > \varepsilon$), so the sense in which they converge should be specified.